# Недопустимый идентификатор

Tags: sql, oracle

Не даёт никак сделать join, без него весь запрос работает

```
select s.studid, 
       s.login,
       s.fsfio,
       s.FSDEPARTMENT,
       s.FCCURR,
       o.FWSEMESTR, 
       --cu.fegnum,
       case 
         when o.FDBEGSES <> 0 then gal_work.to_oradate(o.FDBEGSES)
         else null
       end as sesbeg,
       case 
         when o.FDDATEPROL <> 0 then gal_work.to_oradate(o.FDDATEPROL)
         else null
       end as sesend,
       o.FSNAMBORDER,  
       case
         when o.fddateorder <> 0 then gal_work.to_oradate(o.fddateorder) 
         else null
       end as dateorder
from   gal_public.v_stud_do s, 
       gal_work.U_ORDERPROLONG o 
join   gal_work.U_CURRICULUM cu 
on     cu.FNREC = s.FCCURR
where  o.FCPERSONS = s.PERSONS
order  by sesend desc;
```

Бьет ошибку

> ORA-00904: "S"."FCCURR": недопустимый идентификатор
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

s.FCCURR находит, если перечислить его среди полей для выдачи в select

Comment: Oracle вам намекает, что в таблице `gal_public.v_stud_do` нет такого поля: `FCCURR`

Comment: @MaxU Оно есть, более того если в select его указать, он его отобразит

Comment: Работает ли: `select FCCURR from gal_public.v_stud_do where rownum < 10;`?

Comment: @MaxU да работает

Comment: Вы можете привести в вопросе результат: `desc gal_public.v_stud_do`?

Comment: @MaxU FCCURR             NOT NULL CHAR(16)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы смешали два несовместимых варианта JOIN:

надо либо так:

```
from v_stud_do s
join gal_work.U_ORDERPROLONG o on o.FCPERSONS = s.PERSONS
join gal_work.U_CURRICULUM cu on cu.FNREC = s.FCCURR
```

либо так:

```
from v_stud_do s, gal_work.U_ORDERPROLONG o, gal_work.U_CURRICULUM cu
where o.FCPERSONS = s.PERSONS
  and cu.FNREC = s.FCCURR
```

лично я предпочитаю первый вариант как более читабельный и кроме того - это может облегчить задачу CBO (Cost Based Optimizer)